# How to copy the leftmost n elements in one array into the rightmost n position in another array in reverse order

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, data-structures

So I'm suck on trying to come up with a function that takes in a (int[] X, int n, int[] Y) as parameters and copies the leftmost n elements in X[] into the rightmost n positions in Y[] in reverse order.

so far, I have created a separate function that that prints out the reversal of the leftmost n element in A.

```
public static void reverseArray1(int[] A, int n) {
if(n > 0) {
   System.out.print(A[n-1] + " ");
   reverseArray1(A, n-1);
   }
}
```

This is my program at the moment:

```
class Recursion {
static void reverseArray1(int[] X, int n, int[] Y) {
//This is where I'm stuck

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] A = {-1, 2, 3, 12, 9, 2, -5, -2, 8, 5, 7};
   int[] B = new int[A.length];

   for(int x: A) System.out.print(x+" ");
   System.out.println();

   reverseArray1(A, A.length, B);
   for(int x: B) System.out.print(x+" ");
   System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add a little more, like writing a test method that calls reverseArray1 with an int array of [1, 2, 3, 4] and an n of 3? And maybe print the results and say what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple using recursion:

```
void copyNFromLeft(int[] left, int n, int[] right) {
    if (n < 1)
        return;
    right[right.length - n] = left[n - 1];
    copyNFromLeft(left, n - 1, right);
}
```

You could add some additional checks for indexOutOfBounds cases, e.g. when `n > right.length` (or `left.length`). Basically, something like this:

```
if (n > left.length || n > right.length)
    n = Math.min(left.length, right.length);
```

Comment: Thank you. You just reassured me I was on the right track!

Comment: @HPotter no problem, if an answer helped you resolve your problem, consider marking it as **accepted** to make it clear that your *question is answered*, thanks